# ZeroMQ threads shared object

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq

I have a basic multithreaded C++ application which uses ZeroMQ. It has a ZeroMQ worker thread, and two more threads. These threads share an object which is thread safe, which uses std::mutex inside. When the ZeroMQ thread tries to access the object, application crashes. But it is fine when the other two threads locks the mutex.
Is there a difference between ZeroMQ threads and system threads in this manner?
Thanks

Comment: What is contracting the ZeroMQ thread to cowboy up the same mutual exclusion assurances *worker* threads do? Anything? Is that thread-safe object *internally* thread safe (i.e. your workers make *no* special functional invokes to introduce that safety)? And have you run this in a debugger to see exactly what the point of collapse is?

Comment: @WhozCraig- Actually it is a plugin file(.dll) and it is not possible to debug..Yes it is internally thread-safe.

Comment: If you're talking about zthread's , then there is no difference between them and your OS threads. The crash should at least give you a stack trace that is partly readable in your debugger. And you could always build a debug zeromq or get the pdb symbols for the one you're debugging. if it is indeed basic (stress *basic*) then post a short sample that replicates the problem (*compilable* please).